# How to parallelize simple for loop in native c++ so that it works in visual studio 2010 express

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a very simple for-loop that I want to parallelize (Windows Forms mixed code application):

```
const size_t NumThreads = 4;
class Worker{
   public: void work();
};

vector<T> v(NumThreads); //Number of objects is exactly equal to number of threads
for(size_t i=0; i<NumThreads) v[i].work();
```

"Workers" are completely independent, so I don't have to worry about data races and other multi-threading issues. All I need is to wait for all Workers to finish their work and then proceed further.

But this simple task happened to be a big problem:

- I'd like to use native c++ parallelization as I may later use this classes on Linux.
- OpenMP is not supported in MSVC 2010 Express.
- Boost::Thread does not compile with /clr at all. (Earlier I desperately tried to make Boost::serialization compile and finally surrendered and wrote my own serialization classes).
- std::thread is part of c++11 standard which is not supported in MSVC 2010.

Could you recommend some methods of parallelizing that are in native c++ and guaranteed to be compatible with MSVC 2010 Express? After all, this is a really simple task to parallelize that should not be very complicated even with c-style multi-threading.

Comment: Pre11 C++ doesn't have native threads. You have to use a library, language extension or OS specific api.

Comment: ISO C++ before 2011 had no notion of parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered threading building blocks ([TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/))?  It is supported on both Windows and Linux.

[Here's](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/tutorial-intel-tbb-generic-parallel-algorithms) a quick tutorial.  Here's what you could do:

```
tbb::parallel_for( size_t(0), NumThreads, [&]( size_t i ) {
    v[i].work();
} );
```